# Obtaining string after Last Slash in BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

Let's say I have a column called 'Youtube' and I want to extract the string after the last slash of a URL. How would I do this in BigQuery Standard SQL?

Examples:

```
https://youtube.com/user/HaraldSchmidtShow

https://youtube.com/user/applesofficial

https://youtube.com/user/GrahamColton
```

Essentially, I want:

```
HaraldSchmidtShow

applesofficial

GrahamColton
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative to the previous answer, which also works when there's a '/' at the end:

```
WITH data AS(
  SELECT 'https://youtube.com/user/HaraldSchmidtShow' AS url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://youtube.com/user/applesofficial' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://youtube.com/user/GrahamColton' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://youtube.com/user/GrahamColton/'
)

SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'/([^/]+)/?$') name
FROM `data`
```

Comment: Beat me to it Felipe (also better regex to handle trailing slash ;-))

Answer (score 5):

This might already do the trick for you:

```
WITH data AS(
  SELECT 'https://youtube.com/user/HaraldSchmidtShow' AS url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://youtube.com/user/applesofficial' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://youtube.com/user/GrahamColton'
)

SELECT
  SPLIT(url, '/')[SAFE_OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(url, '/')) - 1)] AS name
FROM `data`
```

It just splits the string and goes for the last value.

Comment: I tried using your solution and did I tried using your solution and did the following but it just gave me a blank column:


SELECT
  SPLIT(youtube, '/')[SAFE_OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(youtube, '/')) - 1)] AS edited_youtube
FROM `data`

Comment: the query technically works but the output is a blank column

Comment: when I use your subquery with the UNION alls, it works but when I use it for my actual data the output is blank. 'youtube' is a string column in my data so the regular expressions should work. 'm confused why it's not working. any ideas?

Comment: hmm not sure. You can bring 'youtube' value as well to check it. Maybe it's not all url's that follows the pattern /user/name

Comment: Yes this is true. There are other types of URLs in the 'youtube' column such as: https://youtube.com/channel/UCEDBbJXgUqRQXCOsluJJ0FQ

Comment: but wouldn't your code work for the last slash in all cases?

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT url, 
  (SELECT v FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(url, '/')) v WITH OFFSET o 
    WHERE v != '' ORDER BY o DESC LIMIT 1
  ) last_string
FROM `data`
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as

```
#standardSQL
WITH data AS(
  SELECT 'https://youtube.com/user/HaraldSchmidtShow' AS url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://youtube.com/user/applesofficial' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://youtube.com/user/GrahamColton/' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'youtube.com/channel/UCEDBbJXgUqRQXCOsluJJ0FQ'
)
SELECT url, 
  (SELECT v FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(url, '/')) v WITH OFFSET o 
    WHERE v != '' ORDER BY o DESC LIMIT 1
  ) last_string
FROM `data`
```

with result

```
Row url                                             last_string  
1   https://youtube.com/user/HaraldSchmidtShow      HaraldSchmidtShow    
2   https://youtube.com/user/applesofficial         applesofficial   
3   https://youtube.com/user/GrahamColton/          GrahamColton     
4   youtube.com/channel/UCEDBbJXgUqRQXCOsluJJ0FQ    UCEDBbJXgUqRQXCOsluJJ0FQ
```

Obviously, using regular expression functions as in Felipe's answer - more elegant and easier to read.
But in some cases using above approach still has practical value so I wanted to bring it to that post